# Partition of unity subordinate to an open cover

Tags: general-topology

Is a partition of unity $\{\phi_{\alpha}\}_{{\alpha}\in A}$ subordinate to an open cover $\mathcal{O}=\{O_{\alpha}\}_{{\alpha}\in A}$ of a smooth manifold $M$ also a cover of $M$?  I ask because subordinate means $\operatorname{supp}(\phi_{\alpha})\subset O_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in A$.  If $\{\phi_{\alpha}\}_{{\alpha}\in A}$ is not a cover then how can a partition of uinity take local properties to global properties which is what they were constructed for?  I question that $\{\phi_{\alpha}\}_{{\alpha}\in A}$ is a cover since $\operatorname{supp}(\phi_{\alpha})\subset O_{\alpha}$; i.e. the values of the function $\phi_{\alpha}$ are identically $0$ for a proper subset of $O_{\alpha}$

Comment: $\{\phi_\alpha\}$ is a collection of function. So by definition, it's not a cover of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection of open sets $U_a=\{\phi_a>0\}$ does yield a cover of your manifold (which is perhaps the intuition you seek?).

Comment: Yes that was how I understand a partition of unity (the domain of the $\phi_{\alpha}>0$ for all $\alpha$ cover of the manifold).  So I guess my original question still applies and I don't understand how we know it covers the manifold.

Comment: It covers because $\sum_a \phi_a(x)=1$ for every $x$ so at least one of the $U_a$ must contain $x$.

Comment: So there must be a lot of overlap of the opens sets corresponding to a particular partition of unity.  Is that a refinement?  Hence the need for a paracompact manifold?

Comment: There are restrictions on what type of manifolds admits a partition of unity. I don't recall exactly what they are, but paracompactness would probably allow for the comstruction.